# An atom of silver has a positive charge of 1e, another atom of silver is of neutral charge. What happens to the charges of both when they're close?

Tags: charge, atomic-physics, atoms

When there is an even number of total charges involved I would assume the total charge would distribute evenly between both atoms. However, when there is an odd total amount of charges involved, what would happen?

Answer (score 0):

For hydrogen the result may be a H$_2^+$ ion. The silver analog of this may also exist.